# Disable "world hillshade" layer from esri/map in JS

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, layers

I'm using arcGis on the web with js api.
I'm creating a new map:

```
new Map({
  basemap: 'topo-vector',
}
```

when i observe the map, i see that besides the 'topo-vector' the is another layer: "world hillshade". How can i remove, or better disable it from the start?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition of "topo-vector" is at https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-Map.html#basemaps-for-others.  If you don't want the hillshade you can create a Basemap with just the other service:

- https://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=7dc6cea0b1764a1f9af2e679f642f0f5

  ```
  let mybasemap = new Basemap({
    baseLayers: [
      new VectorTileLayer({
        portalItem: {
          id: "7dc6cea0b1764a1f9af2e679f642f0f5"
        }
      })
    ],
    title: "Just the topo without hillshade"
  });
  const map = new Map({
    basemap: mybasemap
  });
  ```

Answer (score 1):

Create your own [basemap style](https://www.esri.com/arcgis-blog/products/developers/mapping/design-custom-basemaps-with-the-new-arcgis-vector-tile-style-editor/) based on the Topo Basemap with the Hillshade disabled using the [ArcGIS Vector Tile Style Editor](http://developers.arcgis.com/vector-tile-style-editor/) then use that in your [application](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/display-a-custom-basemap-style/).

[image]